# For a distributive lattice, show $x ~\hat{\land}~ a = y ~\hat{\land}~ a$ and $x ~\hat{\lor}~ a = y ~\hat{\lor}~ a$ imply $x = y$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, lattice-orders

Let $\hat{\land}, \hat{\lor}$ be binary operators denoting the infimum and supremum of two elements in a poset. I was given the following problem.

> For a distributive lattice $\langle ~L, ~\hat{\lor}~, ~\hat{\land}~
>     \rangle$, show that if $x ~\hat{\land}~ a = y ~\hat{\land}~ a$ and $x
>     ~\hat{\lor}~ a = y ~\hat{\lor}~ a$, then $x = y$.

My solution derives from two properties that I do not prove here and can be axiomatically accepted. First, $n \leq n ~\hat{\lor}~ m$. Secondly, that $n \leq m \implies n  =n ~\hat{\land}~m$. Both properties hold for any $(n, m)$ pair in a poset $L$.

Now let us assume that $x ~\hat{\land}~ a = y ~\hat{\land} ~a$. Then, from the aforementioned properties, we have

\begin{align*}
    &x \leq x ~\hat{\lor}~ a \\ 
    \Rightarrow & x = x ~\hat{\land}~ (x ~\hat{\lor}~ a) \\ 
    &= (x ~\hat{\land}~ x) ~\hat{\lor}~ (x ~\hat{\land}~ a) \\ 
    &= x ~\hat{\lor}~ (x ~\hat{\land}~ a) \\ 
    &= x ~\hat{\lor}~ (y ~\hat{\land}~ a) ~ \text{{Assumption}}\\ 
    &= (x ~\hat{\lor}~ y) ~\hat{\land}~ (x ~\hat{\lor}~ a)
.\end{align*}

Using the exact same reasoning, $y = (y ~\hat{\lor}~ x) ~\hat{\land}~ (x
~\hat{\lor}~ a)$. Then $x = y$.

The reason I am unsure of this procedure is that I only made use of one of the preconditions stated in the problem. It seems superflous to assume $x ~\hat{\lor} ~ a = y ~\hat{\lor}~ a$ and it appears that the implication follows solely from assuming $x ~\hat{\land}~ a = y ~\hat{\land} ~a$.

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis in $x ~\hat{\lor}~ x ~\hat{\land}~ a$. The previous element was equal to $x ~\hat{\lor}~ (x ~\hat{\land}~ a)$ and the next one to $(x~\hat{\lor}~ x) ~\hat{\land}~ a.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks, I corrected that but the same doubt remains.

Comment: "Using the exact same reasoning," $y = (y ~\hat{\lor}~ x) ~\hat{\land}~ (y
~\hat{\lor}~ a),$ not $ (y ~\hat{\lor}~ x) ~\hat{\land}~ (x
~\hat{\lor}~ a).$ Now you can use your second assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hinted in comments how to repair your proof, actually needing the two assumptions.

Here is a shorter one, close to yours and dual of that in [Distributive lattice on nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+lattice) (Proposition 2.3):

$$\begin{align*}
    &x \le x ~\hat{\lor}~ a \\ 
    \Rightarrow & x = x ~\hat{\land}~ (x ~\hat{\lor}~ a) \\ 
    &= x ~\hat{\land}~ (y ~\hat{\lor}~ a) ~ \text{{Second assumption}}\\ 
    &= (x ~\hat{\land}~ y) ~\hat{\lor}~ (x ~\hat{\land}~ a)
.\end{align*}
$$

Using the exact same reasoning, $y= (y~\hat{\land}~x) ~\hat{\lor}~ (y~\hat{\land}~ a).$ Therefore (by the first assumption) $x=y.$

Note that the proposition on nLab also sates the converse, i.e. any lattice satisfying this "cancellation law" is distributive.

Comment: Thank you for the comments and for the answer, which was very clear.